# cannot update account due to error message

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to update this users permissions in sql server but it will not allow me. I am getting this pop up message whenever I try. I only see one account for this user. Is there a way to check to see if there are more than one and delete the one that is not in use? Not a dba at all but got tossed into this. Thanks.

[image]

This is the section I'm trying to update. It is from Databases --> security --> login and right clicking.

[image]

It seems to be missing the login name? How can I edit to add?

[image]

Comment: Not creating a new account. I am trying to update this account that is currently there. Just trying to check the box next to a db for this user account after right clicking under security  and properties section in ssms.

Comment: *"Not creating a new account."* This isn't true; if you weren't the error wouldn't be *"**Create** failed for User..."; Error 15023 is specific to you trying to create a User, Group or Role when it already exists in the database.

Comment: In SQL Server there are Logins (at the server) and Users (at the database) ... It looks like you're trying to add this login as a user to the database, but it is already a user in the database, hence the error. Try going to the database in question, open up the security > users node and see if the user is already listed. If so, you can try one of two things - edit the user and try to associate it with the login, or delete it, then re-create it from the login end of it as you're currently trying to do.